# How to pass data(json) to vue instance

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, laravel, vue.js

I have a simple Vue instance and want to pass json from the backend to vue without HTTP request because it's always the same.

I've tried do this with props, but it doesn't work...
In DOM it's looks like `<div id="my-component" prices="[object Object]">`
Vue debug tool show me image as an empty string, and in console `undefined`

```
<div id="my-component" :prices="{{ $prices }}">
</div>

<script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#my-component',
            props: ['prices'],
            mounted: function() {
               console.log(this.image);
           },
       });
</script>
```

where `$prices` json encoded array.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your solution was nearly there but you don't need a prop, rather use a data attribute and assign the JSON via a method:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        json: {},
    },
    methods: {
     setJson (payload) {
         this.json = payload
        },
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" :json="setJson({ foo: 'bar' })">
    <pre>{{ json }}</pre>
</div>
```

You would just assign your Laravel data to the setJson methods payload, i.e.

```
:json="setJson({{ $prices }})
```

Comment: brilliant, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is any Laravel helper for this but I will present a generic approach.

One option would be to store you JSON data in a global variable and the page loads and then use it in your js files.

Basically you need to generate some html similar to:

```
<script>
window.myApp = window.myApp || {};
window.myApp.userData = { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" };
</script>
```

Then from javascript you should be able to access the myApp.userData variable and use it when initializing the Vue component.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        userData: myApp.userData
    }
});
```

Here is an example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    userData: myApp.userData
  }
});
```

```html
<script>
  window.myApp = window.myApp || {};
  window.myApp.userData = { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" };
</script>


<div id="app">
  Hello {{userData.firstName}}
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, this is approach is working. But can it be done without extra variable?Using some binding or smth like that?

Comment: The idea is that you need to expose that information somewhere on the page. This can be done on a variable, on a data attribute etc. Using variables like this (in a namespace) makes it easy to reason about as your application grows.

Comment: Yes, I understand the idea. I've asked about native, vue way. If there no way to do this in a more clear way, I will do this.

Answer (score 1):

I have upvoted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933469/how-to-pass-datajson-to-vue-instance/40934505#40934505#answer-40934505) first, but I have to change my vote (can't do it actually not enough reputation...).

Please do not set the data this way, because it will trigger an error like this:
`[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function`

If anything will use the data you set this way (watch, render components based on it) you will have an infinite loop.

When you use this method:

1. you set the data in the render function (in the template)
2. if something triggers a re-render, the data will be set again
3. anything using this data will have to re-render, which may cause a
   re-render on the main vue instance

This will cause the infinite loop.

LinusBorg have an explanation [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-warning-you-may-have-an-infinite-update-loop-in-a-component-render-function/48564#post_2).

Answer (score 0):

While this op is old, here is how I would do it (inspired by how I do it in Symfony 4 + VueJS):

```html
<div id="my-component" prices-data="{{ json($prices) }}">
</div>

<script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#my-component',
            props: ['pricesData'],
            data: {
               prices: null,
            },
            mounted: function() {
               this.prices = JSON.parse(this.pricesData);
           },
       });
</script>
```

This is obviously assuming that $prices is a blade variable.

> Note: I used @json() above when $prices is a simple object that can be encoded with json_encode() (underlying function being used when you call blade json function. If however the object is complex, consider using [JMS Serializer](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer) with @MaxDepth annotations if objects become too complex.