# How to pass Laravel data(json) to Vue component

Tags: json, laravel, parsing, vue.js

I want to pass an Laravel object to my Vue component. In Vue I want to parse the data to an JSON object and I already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933469/how-to-pass-datajson-to-vue-instance).

In my blade I have this:

```
<creator :object="parseData({{ $object->toJson() }})"></creator>
```

And in my component I have this:

```
data() {
    return {
        object: null
    }
},
methods: {
    parseData(data) {
        this.object= JSON.parse(data);
    }
}
```

I also tried

```
props: ['object']
```

instead of data()

This gives me the following error:

`[Vue warn]: Property or method "parseData" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.`

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

**SOLVED**
I tried it again today and for some reason it worked. Thanks for your time guys!

Answer (score 1):

Your `parseData` method needs to be defined within the `methods` section of your JS.

Try:

```
data() {
    return {
        ball: null
    }
},

methods: {
   parseData(data) {
      this.object= JSON.parse(data);
   }
}
```

Edit: and do what  @Piotr said :)

Comment: Thank you for mentioning, I already have this in my Code, just forgot to write it correct in stackoverflow. So the erros is still the same

Answer (score 1):

**First:** You didn't add property `object` to your component. To fix this you have to add this line

```
props: ['object'],
```

just before your `data` function.

**Second:** you have to define `parseData` function in `methods` part of your component. Fix it as follows:

```
methods: {
    parseData () {
        //your function logic
    }
}
```

Vue needs to define methods, watchers,  computed properties within proper section.

Now your code is compete.

Comment: Oh I forgot to write down the methods section in stackoverflow, but I already have that correct in my code. Either way I try it with props: ['object'] or data() { return { object: null }} I got the same error